# Highstock monthly data step-area chart issue with last point

Tags: jquery, highcharts, area

I'm working on an highstock step-area chart.
My data are monthly, so I want them to be plotted as constant from the first to the last day of every month.
However, as you can see in this http://jsfiddle.net/d7292owr/5/:

```
$(function () {

  $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

        title: {
            text: 'Data of the month'
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1,
            enabled: false
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Temperature',
            //data: temperatures,
            step: 'left',
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2004, 3, 1), // first of April
            pointInterval: 3600 * 1000 * 24 * 31, // hourly data
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 1,
                valueSuffix: '°C'
            },
            data:  [
                    [1404194400000.00,9.233],
                    [1406872800000.00,10.699],
                    [1409551200000.00,11.756]
                    ]
        }]
    });
});
```

the line of the last month always stops on the first day and pointInterval is useless.

Thanks in advance

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Why don't you use `step: 'center'` instead of left? http://jsfiddle.net/d7292owr/6/ is this what you want?

Comment: Thank you, but no, it's not what I want.

Comment: The chart will have just one value for every month and every month should have the same lenght, just as in a column chart. I hope I have been clear

Comment: In case when your data is until 1.09, line is printed this time, so what is incorrect in that?

Comment: Every month I will publish just one value. It doesn't matter what's the day, 1st, 15th or 31th. I just expect the chart to plot a complete step. The same you could see plotting: 1/09/2014: 12°C - 30/09/2014: 12°C (constant).

Comment: More specifically, the day of the month in which I publish data is conventional. So, it'll always be the 1st, but I want the chart to show that the data is valid and constant until the last day of the month itself.

Comment: The problem is that highcharts not predict your values, so when last point is 1.09, then it is end at this point. You need to add extra point in the end of chart or modify pointInterval / pointStart.